# makefile used compile program in Mac and cross compiler flags it uses in it.what they means & alternative 4 the flags if I am not using cross-compiler

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cross-compiling

I have a simple OS and Bootloader code downloaded from https://github.com/FRosner/FrOS/tree/minimal-c-kernel

tutorial is at https://dev.to/frosnerd/writing-my-own-boot-loader-3mld

I have some questions about the make file

in below makefile what is `x86_64-elf-ld`, ld I belive is to link the object files and libraries into output .a and bin files which are libraries. So I believe to output a library called `kernel.bin` the author used ld's `-o` flag since its linker then the output is .bin file. I like to know can I output .o file from ld program (by using only ld program can I output .o binary executable, if no, then I assumed its a linker not compiler and compiler can output only executable/**or self executable with main()** and linker can output only library which needed by some other executable code to call its functions )

the first line is noticed is

```
kernel.bin: kernel_entry.o kernel.o
        x86_64-elf-ld -m elf_i386 -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary
```

since the author built the program in Mac computer and wanted to output binary from code that runs on x86-64 architecture so he needed `x86-64` linker which is `x86_64-elf-ld` and can be easily installed on Mac. But I do not have Mac, I have x86-64 computer then can I use only `ld` instead of cross platform `ld`  which is `x86_64-elf-ld` on authors computer  also what is `-m` flag? does `-m` is an option and `elf_i386` is a value of the option `-m`, can any one please clarify this. or are they (-m and elf_i386 are two separate things if yes then what they mean?) and is with flag `-Ttext` can I specify the address of output file? so what exactly above two lines means along with there flags

this is next  is

```
kernel_entry.o: kernel_entry.asm
    nasm $< -f elf -o $@
```

what is `-f`  flag and what is elf in above two lines? in above its output-ing .o `$@ target` file which is executable. with NASM assembly compiler

so in rest of the makefile what are `-m32,-b,-f,-ffreestanding,-fda` flags and what is xxd program?

These are many questions or someone just direct me to some page where I will not like to  be lost in dozens of flags. May concise page where these flags can be covered. Or if some one take time to explain them then very thanks

```
# $@ = target file
# $< = first dependency
# $^ = all dependencies

# First rule is the one executed when no parameters are fed to the Makefile
all: run

# Notice how dependencies are built as needed
kernel.bin: kernel_entry.o kernel.o
    x86_64-elf-ld -m elf_i386 -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary

kernel_entry.o: kernel_entry.asm
    nasm $< -f elf -o $@

kernel.o: kernel.c
    x86_64-elf-gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@

# Disassemble
kernel.dis: kernel.bin
    ndisasm -b 32 $< > $@

mbr.bin: mbr.asm
    nasm $< -f bin -o $@

os-image.bin: mbr.bin kernel.bin
    cat $^ > $@

run: os-image.bin
    qemu-system-i386 -fda $<

echo: os-image.bin
    xxd $<

clean:
    $(RM) *.bin *.o *.dis
```

Comment: I think that lots of you questions can be answered by a simple google search (e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=xxd) and a look at the **manual pages**. a good resource for os development is https://wiki.osdev.org/ e.g. https://wiki.osdev.org/Why_do_I_need_a_Cross_Compiler%3F and https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

Comment: @MarcoLucidi yes I did this now the only question I have is `why I have to resort to using x86_64-elf-ld linker and x86_64-elf-gcc compiler` since the author used them because he was not developinh makefile and program on x86-64. But why I have to use them. So question actually is now: can I use only gcc instead of x86_64-elf-gcc cross compiler and can I use ld as linker instead of x86_64-elf-ld cross platform linker.Can u please tell me this Since I like to compile and link the program on my system which actually is x86-64 bit intel processor. This only I like to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now the only question I have is **why I have to resort to using
> x86_64-elf-ld linker and x86_64-elf-gcc compiler** since the author used
> them because he was not developinh makefile and program on x86-64. But
> why I have to use them. So question actually is now: **can I use only
> gcc instead of x86_64-elf-gcc cross compiler and can I use ld as
> linker instead of x86_64-elf-ld cross platform linker**.

in short, it is recommended to use a cross compiler when developing an os because it:

> allows you to leave the current operating system behind, meaning that
> no headers or libraries of your host operating system will be used.
> You need a cross-compiler for operating system development, otherwise
> a lot of unexpected things can happen because the compiler assumes
> that your code is running on your host operating system.

for more information see:

- [Why do I need a Cross Compiler?](https://wiki.osdev.org/Why_do_I_need_a_Cross_Compiler%3F)
- [GCC Cross-Compiler](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler)

hence, even if you are on `x86-64` it is still recommended to use a cross compiler, because it will save you a lot of trouble.

as for the linker, on osdev.org they recommend to:

> **Linking with your compiler rather than ld**
>
> You shouldn't be invoking ld directly. Your cross-compiler is able to
> work as a linker and using it as the linker allows it control at the
> linking stage. This control includes expanding the -lgcc to the full
> path of libgcc that only the compiler knows about. If you get weird
> errors during compilation, use your cross-compiler for linking and it
> may go away. If you do need ld, be sure to use the cross-linker
> (i686-elf-ld) rather than the system linker.

see also: https://wiki.osdev.org/Category:FAQ

Comment: can u please tell. Do making changes to linux kernel and changing and creating and building it for this: is gcc also used to compile and link object files. does MAKE uses gcc or cross compiler of gcc:to build after developers editing  the kernel does MAKE use gcc or its cross compiler version. does make use gcc or cross compiler of gcc to compile linux kernel/ubuntu kernel/etc.? are u understanding my question in this comment does Make uses gcc?

Comment: I think I found the answer by searching https://www.google.com/search?q=can+gcc+be+used+to+build+real+operating+system&oq=can+gcc+be+used+to+build+real+operating+system&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160.18924j0j7&client=ms-android-samsung-gj-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. It's very useful. I am now all into learning linux kernel and embedded systems. Also can u please tell the link u posted in answer about cross compiler. It says for building os i also need g++ why is that. Why c++ compiler which has nothing to do with c code of os kernel and is embedded system code. I only knows g++ use c++ programs compiling (is it also a linker as well as compiler for c++ libraries and executables .o files?

Comment: @user786 you are welcome! I think that the linux kernel can be built using "normal" `gcc` from linux itself i.e. using linux as the "host" operating system. as for `g++`, it's only required to build the cross compiler because `gcc` is (partially) written in c++.

Comment: Just last question. I was wondering can I use tcp to debug kernel using kgdb and gdb. Although its unrelated. But I was just wondering. My laptop does not have functionality to be one of the computer to get connected with my desktop computer required in debugging. Can u please tell by simple yes or no answer. May be a single link

Comment: And exact name for gcc cross compiler for x86-64 in `sudo apt install xxx` If I like to install cross compiler

Comment: @user786 I'm sorry, I never used `kgdb` and remote debugging, I don't know how it works. as for `gcc` cross compiler, I don't think it's already packaged in `apt` repos, you have to build it from sources. follow the guide on osdev I posted in my answer, dependencies are listed here: https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler#Preparing_for_the_build